# g.drawstring string from String[]

Tags: java, string, draw, arrays

I try to draw strings from String[]. This code doesen't seem to work. It's supposed to be somekind of chatsystem.. I'm also wondering if this is good or bad way to make chat system? For example is there some better way to "empty" part?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ChatSystem {
public static boolean ChatOpen = false;
public static int ChatHeight = 400;
public static int ChatWidth = 400;
public static String[] LastWords;
public static String[] UpdateWords;
public static boolean empty = true;

public static void SomeOneSpoke(String words){
    for(int x = 0; x<5;x++){
    LastWords[x] = UpdateWords[x];
    LastWords[x+1] = UpdateWords[x];
    LastWords[x] = words;
    }
}

public static void GameText(String words){
    for(int x = 0; x<5;x++){
    LastWords[x] = UpdateWords[x];
    LastWords[x+1] = UpdateWords[x];
    LastWords[x] = words;
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    if(empty == true){
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        LastWords[x] = "";  
        }
    }
        g.drawImage(new ImageIcon("pictures/interfaces/Interface1.png").getImage(), 0, Screen.myHeight-ChatHeight, ChatWidth, ChatHeight, null);
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        g.drawString(LastWords[x], 15, (Screen.myHeight-20)-(x*30));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a chatsystem with "normal" components, such as a JTextArea for the text?

Comment: o.o Never heard of that kind of component xD Thank you.. maybe I should try that one.. :) Thank you

Comment: Note that if you draw an empty string, there is just nothing drawn - it does not, as you might expect, overwrite any existing pixels.

Comment: @minisurma If your a begginner with Swing, I advice you to look at this [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), the menu can be seen like an overview of all the component :)

Comment: @Jack yes, that's what I wanted :D

Comment: Actually I think I should do it using g.drawString, because I would like to add custom smiles and things like that.. So how could I use g.drawString() to present chat?

Comment: If you want images, then use a JEditorPane or JTextPane.  This is what they're *for*.  Don't invent work for yourself.  See the tutorial as @Nizil suggested.  It's all there.

Comment: ohh, okies :) Thanks every1